# Differences in proportion of variance explained by MuMin and r2glmm packages using the nsj method

Tags: mixed-model

I estimated the proportion of variance explained by the fixed predictors of a linear mixed model using both packages `MuMIn` and `r2glmm` however when I use the `nsj` method I get R2c and R2m with the MuMIn of 0.217 and with the r2glmm an r2  of 0.42.  The difference is even larger if I use the sgv method.  Why is this?

I was hoping both estimates were similar.

My model:

```
modeltemp4<-lme((S1_93_11) ~(MSperDA)+MEANELEVSMO+DivDASqKM, 
corGaus(form=~jlat+jlon), method = "ML", 
weights=varIdent(form=~1|Contrast),random= ~ 1|Contrast,data=Priest, control = 
lmeControl(opt = 'optim') )

r2=r2beta(modeltemp4,partial=TRUE,method='nsj', data=NULL)
> r2
       Effect   Rsq upper.CL lower.CL
1       Model 0.418    0.563    0.284
4   DivDASqKM 0.210    0.366    0.082
2     MSperDA 0.130    0.278    0.028
3 MEANELEVSMO 0.092    0.232    0.011

r.squaredGLMM(modeltemp4) =0.2168
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an explanation for this same mistake that I've also found. In my case, the differences are even greater. I copy down the values of the marginal R2 in case it is useful to find an explanation or identify a problem with one of the functions. In my case, the different functions estimated the values:

```
MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM = 0.48
r2glmm::r2beta (method='nsj') = 0.04
```

These two above are supposed to give the same

```
r2glmm::r2beta (method='sgv') = 0.16
rsq::rsq(adj=F) = 0.08
rsq::rsq(adj=T) = 0.07
```

My impression is that the function *r.squaredGLMM* of the MuMin package might have some error.

The authors of the r2glmm package say in the "README" document that the method "sgv" is more stable. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/r2glmm/README.html).

P.S. I'm sorry for not including the code in the example, but I don't know how I could leave the data used accessible for another user to check the veracity of the differences.

Comment: `r2beta` is equivalent to marginal R^2 (`"r2m"` in `r.squaredGLMM` result). Also, `r.squaredGLMM` follows closely the code in Nakagawa et al. 2017 paper while, as much as I can see, `r2beta` does not.